# Group date in month and year php date

Tags: php

I have values

> 05 May 2016,
>   19 May 2016,
>   26 May 2016,
>   02 June 2016,
>   16 June 2016,
>   23 June 2016,
>   07 July 2016,
>   14 July 2016

How can I show this with PHP as:

> 05,19,26 May 2016 
>   02, 16,23 June 2016  
>   07,14 July 2016

Comment: `05 May 2016, 19 May 2016, 26 May 2016, 02 June 2016, 16 June 2016, 23 June 2016, 07 July 2016, 14 July 2016` is one string or are these multiple strings in an array?

Comment: value from array mysql

Comment: How do you stock the date in your DB ?

Comment: like('2016-05-20'),
('2016-05-27'),
('2016-04-21'),
('2016-05-05'),
('2016-05-01'),
('2016-05-05'),
('2016-05-12'),
('2016-05-19'),
('2016-05-26'),
('2016-05-14'),
('2016-06-10'),
('2016-06-24'),
('2016-04-27'),
('2016-04-28'),
('2016-04-30');

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is ordered something like this piece of code should work:

```
<?php
$str = '05 May 2016, 19 May 2016, 26 May 2016, 02 June 2016, 16 June 2016, 23 June 2016, 07 July 2016, 14 July 2016';
$arr = explode(',',$str); //
$results = array();
$currResStr = '';
$lastMonth = '';
$lastYear = '';
$appendMonth = false;
$elCount = count($arr);
for ($i=0; $i < $elCount; $i++) {
    preg_match("/([0-9]{2})\s([a-zA-z]+)\s([0-9]*)/", $arr[$i], $match);
    if($i+1 < $elCount){
        preg_match("/([0-9]{2})\s([a-zA-z]+)\s([0-9]*)/", $arr[$i+1], $match2);
        if($match[2] !== $match2[2]){
            $appendMonth = true;
        }else{
            $appendMonth = false;
        }
        if($appendMonth || $i+1 >= count($arr)){
            $currResStr .= $match[1].' '.$match[2].' '.$match[3];
            array_push($results,$currResStr);
            $currResStr = '';
        }else{
            $currResStr .= $match[1].',';
        }
    }else{
        $currResStr .= $match[1].' '.$match[2].' '.$match[3];
        array_push($results,$currResStr);
    }
}
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Prints out:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(17) "05,19,26 May 2016" [1]=> string(18) "02,16,23 June 2016" [2]=> string(15) "07,14 July 2016" }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are my three steps:

1. Explode on commas
2. Loop to assign temporary keys which serve to group the dates
3. Loop to display the values

Code:

```
$string='05 May 2016, 19 May 2016, 26 May 2016, 02 June 2016, 16 June 2016, 23 June 2016, 07 July 2016, 14 July 2016';
foreach(explode(', ',$string) as $date){
    $groups[substr($date,3)][]=substr($date,0,2);
}
foreach($groups as $monthyear=>$days){
    echo implode(',',$days)," $monthyear<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
05,19,26 May 2016
02,16,23 June 2016
07,14 July 2016
```

For the same result, you could use a second explode in the first loop like this:

```
foreach(explode(', ',$string) as $date){
    $parts=explode(' ',$date,2);
    $groups[$parts[1]][]=$parts[0];
}
foreach($groups as $monthyear=>$days){
    echo implode(',',$days)," $monthyear<br>";
}
```